# Regex to select unencoded ampersands within anchor / href attribute

Tags: html, regex, xhtml, replace, sublimetext2

I would like to use my text editor to find un-encoded ampersands (`&`) which are inside `<a>` tags or an `href` attribute, so that I can encode those ampersands.  The regex should **not** find any ampersands within script tags, HTML comments (conditional comments), or any ampersands which are already encoded.

So far, I have:

```
&(?!amp;)
```

While it doesn't match already encoded ampersands, it does match inside comments and script tags.  Here are the text conditions I'm using:

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]-->

<a href="blog.html?id=1&amp;height=471&flexible=0&post_limit=1">

<script>
if something && another
 { do stuff; }
</script>
```

How can I prevent the regex from matching `&` when inside scripts and comments?

Comment: According to the [DOCs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html), SublimeText uses the [Boost Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), that said: To complete this task you will have to look behind (and ahead). The problem is, lookbehind in Perl *must* be of fixed length, and you don't have a fixed length. Which means your task is impossible to accomplish unless you want to match the whole tag `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using capturing parentheses and back references:

Search: `(<a.*)&(?!amp;)(.*)` Replace: `\1&amp;\2`

In my testing (Aptana Studio) this requires doing the search/replace multiple times if a line has multiple unencoded ampersands (but if I hold down Alt+d to do the Replace/Find, the whole file is updated very quickly).

Comment: fyi `<>` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: It needs to only match the `&`, otherwise the replace action will stomp over all the query sting bits.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize you were doing search/replace. You could try using capturing parentheses and back references:

Search: `(<a.*)&(?!amp;)(.*)`
Replace: `\1&amp;\2`

In my testing (Aptana Studio) this requires doing the search/replace multiple times if a line has multiple unencoded ampersands (but if I hold down Alt+d to do the Replace/Find, the whole file is updated very quickly).

Comment: @AlienBishop - The search and replace string in your comment works, though I do have to search multiple times if multiple un-encoded amperands exist in a single tag.  Can you update your answer with the info from the comment?